# Django admin list filter on reverse relationship

Tags: django, filter, django-admin

I have two django models:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='orders')
    shipping_address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=9)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

class OrderStatus(models.Model):
    STATUS_ACCEPTED = 1
    STATUS_PROCESSING = 2
    STATUS_DELIVERING = 3
    STATUS_COMPLETED = 4
    CODE_CHOICES = (
        (STATUS_ACCEPTED, 'accepted'),
        (STATUS_PROCESSING, 'processing'),
        (STATUS_DELIVERING, 'delivering'),
        (STATUS_COMPLETED, 'completed'),
    )
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    code = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=CODE_CHOICES)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='status_list')
```

Normally if I wanted to get all the orders with 'accepted' status I could write Order.objects.filter(orderstatus__code=1).

But how can I make django admin to create OrderStatus list filter?

I have googled a lot and found only one answer here on stackoverflow, which claims simply adding reverse model ('orderstatus' in my case) to list_filter tuple should work, but I get an error message: `The value of 'list_filter[1]' refers to 'orderstatus', which does not refer to a Field.`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try by you self before posting question here, because there are lots of question related to this one, Any way i think this link will help you.

https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-admin-cookbook/en/latest/many_to_many.html

Comment: Your link leads to my questoin. 

I tried by myself and searched for a solution but the only thing I found was this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37120654/django-filter-in-admin-on-reverse-related-field

which did not work out for me as I said.

Answer (score 0):

> `The value of 'list_filter[1]' refers to 'orderstatus', which does not refer to a Field.`

This is because `orderstatus` is not a field in your model. Either change `order` field to `orderstatus` or change the name passed to `list_filter` to the name of your field.